# I am not able to install google chrome in my oracle enterprise linux

Tags: linux, google-chrome, 64-bit, rpm, lsb

I have created a google.repo file and stored the file in yum.repos.d, the contents of google.repo are :

```
[google-chrome]
name=google-chrome – 64-bit
baseurl=http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/rpm/stable/x86_64
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub
```

I executed the below command in shell as a root user :

Executed :

```
yum install google-chrome-stable
```

Output :

```
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package google-chrome-stable.x86_64 0:23.0.1271.64-165188 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: lsb >= 4.0 for package: google-chrome-stable
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.11)(64bit) for package: google-chrome-stable
--> Processing Dependency: libcurl.so.4()(64bit) for package: google-chrome-stable
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
google-chrome-stable-23.0.1271.64-165188.x86_64 from google-chrome has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: libcurl.so.4()(64bit) is needed by package google-chrome-stable-23.0.1271.64-165188.x86_64 (google-chrome)
google-chrome-stable-23.0.1271.64-165188.x86_64 from google-chrome has depsolving problems      
 --> Missing Dependency: lsb >= 4.0 is needed by package google-chrome-stable-23.0.1271.64-165188.x86_64 (google-chrome)
google-chrome-stable-23.0.1271.64-165188.x86_64 from google-chrome has depsolving problems
 --> Missing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.11)(64bit) is needed by package google-chrome-stable-23.0.1271.64-165188.x86_64 (google-chrome)
Error: Missing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.11)(64bit) is needed by package google-chrome-stable-23.0.1271.64-165188.x86_64 (google-chrome)
Error: Missing Dependency: libcurl.so.4()(64bit) is needed by package google-chrome-stable-23.0.1271.64-165188.x86_64 (google-chrome)
Error: Missing Dependency: lsb >= 4.0 is needed by package google-chrome-stable-23.0.1271.64-165188.x86_64 (google-chrome)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                    package-cleanup --dupes
                    rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
The program package-cleanup is found in the yum-utils package.
```

I can't find lsb package also, I found that the below packages are installed : 
redhat-lsb.x86_64 
redhat-lsb.i386

Please help me to install google chrome in oracle enterprise linux 5...

Answer (score 3):

alright, it seems that OL 5 has older version of GLIBC and chrome will not work with that.

https://superuser.com/questions/393158/how-to-install-a-chrome-on-my-rhel-5-3-box

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind installing an earlier version of Google Chrome which does not requires latest libstdc++.so, read the following:

For example, for Oracle Linux 6.6 (64bit), google chrome version 35 or higher requires libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.15). Go to http://orion.lcg.ufrj.br/RPMS/myrpms/google/ and download google-chrome-stable-27.0.1453.110-202711.x86_64.rpm. Run the following command

```
sudo yum install /path-to/google-chrome-stable-27.0.1453.110-202711.x86_64.rpm
```

FYI - To check what versions of libstdc++ your system has, do the following

```
strings /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX
```